# Which inflammatory response with Cytomegalovirus infection?

Tags: pathology, virus, inflammation

I am thinking about inflammation process with Cytomegalovirus infection.
I first thought it is about chronic inflammation, but then changed my mind because of virus infection.
I think cytokines must be there in activation.

I am thinking which of these is right mechanism for both of these

- mononuclear cells and granulocytes (I think this must be chronic inflammation)
- granulocytes with scar formation (I think no scar)
- cytopathic cytoproliferation inflammation

I think the cytopathic cytoproliferation inflammation is the right one because cytokines are activating the inflammatory response in virus infection.
However, I am not sure if this inflammation is of chronic type.

**Which type of inflammation can cytomegalovirus infection lead to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this paper the virus triggers the innate immune system and induces inflammatory cytokines as well as interferon stimulated genes (which is a response to a viral infection).
It seems to be recognized by the cells via the Toll-like receptor 2 and CD14, which subsequently trigger the cytokine production. A schematic view comes from the second paper:

[image]

These two articles are interesting in this context, the first addresses CMV in special,
the second is a pretty recent review about how viruses are recognized and how cytokines are involved:

- [Human cytomegalovirus activates inflammatory cytokine responses via
  CD14 and Toll-like receptor 2.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12663765)
- [Learning from the messengers: innate sensing of viruses and cytokine
  regulation of immunity - clues for treatments and vaccines.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23435233)